# SQL - retrieval query for specific string

Tags: sql

I am making a small database at the moment (less than 50 entries) and I am having trouble with a query. My query at the moment is

```
SELECT  Name
FROM Customers 
WHERE Name LIKE '%Adam%'
```

The names are in the format of "Adam West".

The query works fine in retrieving all the people with "Adam" in their name but I would like to only retrieve the first name, not the last name. I don't want to split the columns up but would like to know how to rewrite my query to account for this.

Comment: First name and last name saparated by space ?

Comment: You should split the column or duplicate it even. But if data in column start with name just remove the `%` from your query and go to a tutorial that will you explain why.

Comment: You haven't given enough information.  For example, if names are written as `'Joe Bloggs'` you'd get different answers than if your names are written as `'Bloggs, Joe'`.  Additionally, you are better served storing each part of the name in separate fields *(one called first_name, one called last_name)* and you have not advised us why you can not (or will not) change the data structure.

Comment: @MatBailie it is in the format of "Adam West".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT  Name
FROM Customers 
WHERE Name LIKE 'Adam%'

Answer (score 1):

if you are storing name with space as separator example "Adam abcd" where 'Adam' is firstname and 'abcd' as lastname then following will work

```
SELECT     Expr1
FROM         (SELECT     LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name, 1)) AS Expr1
                       FROM          Customers) AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE     (Expr1 LIKE 'Adm%')
```

for more details read this article http://suite101.com/article/sql-functions-leftrightsubstrlengthcharindex-a209089

Comment: sorry one typo WHERE(Expr1 LIKE 'Adam%')

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your customers starts with first name (like *Adam West*) you can use

```
select Name
from Customers
where Name like 'Adam %'
```

Otherwise, if the format of the name is `<last name> <first name>` you can use

```
select Name
from Customers
where Name like '% Adam'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

{SELECT  Name
FROM Customers 
WHERE SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Name)-1) LIKE '%Adam%'
}

I assumed the first name and last name is saparated by space and i took the firstname out

Using SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Name)-1)
and compared how you wanted. if your have something else saparating first name and last name change space in charindex with the saparater.

Please let me know if any other help needed.

Regards

Ashutosh

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed "split" your columns and normalize your tables to avoid having to use complicated string functions to search for a lastname or firstname or what ever you need to look for. What about if someone entered lastname first and then firstname? Or just a nickname?

That said, check the use of `LIKE` on [Microsoft technet site](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms179859.aspx). The following query should be helpful on you case:

```
SELECT Name
  FROM Customers
 WHERE Name LIKE 'Adam%'
```